# Kotlin Flow: callbackFlow with lazy initializer of callback object

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-flow, kotlin-coroutines

I want to use reactive paradigm using `Kotlin Flow` in my Android project. I have an external callback-based API so my choice is using `callbackFlow` in my `Repository` class.

I've already read insightfully some proper docs with no help:

- [callbackFlow documentation](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/callback-flow.html)
- [Callbacks and Kotlin Flows](https://elizarov.medium.com/callbacks-and-kotlin-flows-2b53aa2525cf) by Roman Elizarov

What I want to achieve:

Currently my `Repository` class looks like this (simplified code):

```
lateinit var callback: ApiCallback

fun someFlow() = callbackFlow<SomeModel> {
    callback = object : ApiCallback {
        override fun someApiMethod() {
            offer(SomeModel())
        }
    }

    awaitClose { Log.d("Suspending flow until methods aren't invoked") }
}

suspend fun someUnfortunateCallbackDependentCall() {
    externalApiClient.externalMethod(callback)
}
```

Problem occurs when `someUnfortunateCallbackDependentCall` is invoked faster than collecting `someFlow()`.
For now to avoid `UninitializedPropertyAccessException` I added some delays in my coroutines before invoking `someUnfortunateCallbackDependentCall` but it is kind of hack/code smell for me.

My first idea was to use `by lazy` instead of `lateinit var` as this is what I want - lazy initialization of callback object. However, I couldn't manage to code it altogether. I want to emit/offer/send some data from `someApiMethod` to make a data flow but going outside of `callbackFlow` would require `ProducerScope` that is in it. And on the other hand, `someUnfortunateCallbackDependentCall` is not Kotlin Flow-based at all (could be suspended using `Coroutines` API at best).

Is it possible to do? Maybe using some others Kotlin delegates? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question technically, you can of course intialise a callback lazyily or with lateinit, but you can't do this AND share the coroutine scope (one for the Flow and one for the suspend function) at the same time - you need to build some kind of synchronisation yourself.

Below I've made some assumptions about what you are trying to achieve, perhaps they are not perfect for you, but hopefully give some incite into how to improve.

Since it is a Repository that you are creating, I will first assume that you are looking to store `SomeModel` and allow the rest of your app to observe changes to it. If so, the easiest way to do this is with a `MutableStateFlow` property instead of a `callbackFlow`:

```
interface Repository {
    val state: Flow<SomeModel>
    suspend fun reload()
}

class RepositoryImpl(private val service: ApiService) : Repository {

    override val state = MutableStateFlow(SomeModel())

    override suspend fun reload() {
        return suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
            service.callBackend(object : ApiCallback {
                override fun someApiMethod(data: SomeModel) {
                    state.value = data
                    if (continuation.context.isActive)
                        continuation.resume(Unit)
                }
            })
        }
    }
}

interface ApiCallback {
    fun someApiMethod(data: SomeModel)
}

data class SomeModel(val data: String = "")

interface ApiService {
    fun callBackend(callback: ApiCallback)
}
```

The downside to this solution is that you have to call `reload()` in order to actually make a call to your backend, collecting the Flow alone is not enough.

```
myrepository.state.collect {} 
myrepository.reload()
```

Another solution, again depending on what exactly you are trying to achieve, is to provide two ways to call your backend:

```
interface Repository {
    fun someFlow(): Flow<SomeModel>
    suspend fun reload(): SomeModel
}

class RepositoryImpl(private val service: ApiService) : Repository {

    override fun someFlow() = callbackFlow<SomeModel> {
        service.callBackend(object : ApiCallback {
            override fun someApiMethod(data: SomeModel) {
                offer(data)
            }
        })
        awaitClose {
            Log.d("TAG", "Callback Flow is closed")
        }
    }

    override suspend fun reload(): SomeModel {
        return suspendCoroutine<SomeModel> { continuation ->
            service.callBackend(object : ApiCallback {
                override fun someApiMethod(data: SomeModel) {
                    if (continuation.context.isActive)
                        continuation.resume(data)
                }
            })
        }
    }
}

interface ApiCallback {
    fun someApiMethod(data: SomeModel)
}

data class SomeModel(val data: String = "")

interface ApiService {
    fun callBackend(callback: ApiCallback)
}
```

Now you can either call `reload()` *or* `someFlow()` to retrieve `SomeModel()` and the `Repository` holds no "state".

Note that the `reload()` function is simply a 'coroutine' version of the `callbackFlow` idea.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Your first solution feels a bit hacky as I'm using MVI architecture and keeping state in Repository is not I would prefer. Second solution might work but unfortunately I think it won't well in this specific API implementation. There are some quite lengthy Callbacks here, in each callback method I'm using Kotlin-Flow specific ones like offer/send. To better illustrate the problem, I'm using Nearby Connections API made by Google. If you could, please take a look on ConnectionLifecycleCallback syntax and its usage in startAdvertising() method. Thanks again for your help.